# find a specific format of pattern mysql with REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex

dears

i want to match all records with this formula XXX:XXXXX where X any number from 0-9

ie 123:12312 333:09102 etc

i tried:

`select * from table where field REGEXP  '^*[0-9][0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*$'`

but it doesn't work

Comment: The `*` is a quantifier. This `^*` isn't quantifying anything, the `^` is the start of the column. I'd try `^\d{3}:\d{5}$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be work to check the REGEXP

```
SELECT 
  '123:12345'  REGEXP '^[0-9]\{3\}:[0-9]\{5\}$',
  '123:123456' REGEXP '^[0-9]\{3\}:[0-9]\{5\}$',
  '123:A2345'  REGEXP '^[0-9]\{3\}:[0-9]\{5\}$',
  'A23:12345' REGEXP '^[0-9]\{3\}:[0-9]\{5\}$',
  '123:12345' REGEXP '^[0-9]\{3\}:[0-9]\{5\}$';
```

Comment: lets be more specific if i want to match any string that include this 123:3XXXX
for example this string will be matched "123213123 123:31234 23432432"